# Save and update a json file with a foreign key?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I need to save some data about a merchandise in a database and in a json file.

I have a name,and a category, that is a foreign key.

How can I have a structure like that in a json file? And can I?

I would need something like this...

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"Merchandise #1",
"category":{
  "id":1,
  "name":"category #1"
  }
}
```

How can I save and edit this file? Do I do it as it is normal,how do I treat this category part? If I do,do I duplicate the category name and id for every entry?

My model classes would be:

```
public class Category
{

public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}

}

public class Merchandise
{

public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}

public int categoryId {get; set;}    
public Category category {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You may or may not need to serialize the entire `Category` object, but that depends on what you are doing. If you are trying to pass data from an API to a client app that will display the category name alongside the merchandise information (e.g. in a list of merchandise), you will probably want to include the category name, and possibly the category Id. However, if you are passing data from the client to the API, to, for example, update the category of a merchandise, you do not need to include the category name, just the Id.

Comment: I need to save the data in my database and in my .json file.And I need to list it, the merch and the category name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the code for saving the data...Edit is similar.

```
 private void MerchInsert()
    {          
        RootObject product = new RootObject();
        product.name = "Apple";
        product.id = 3;

        Category cat = new Category();
        cat.id = 3;
        cat.name = "category";
        product.category = cat;
        string objjsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
        File.WriteAllText(jsonFileM, objjsonData);
   }
```